# How to get contacts which are used in whatsapp or other application in android

Tags: android, contacts, whatsapp, viber

Hi i want to get contact which are used by other application (like whatsapp or viber )
please see in below image

[image]

please help me about this issue
thanks

Comment: Start here: http://developer.android.com/samples/BasicContactables/index.html

Comment: hi how to find ex mobile number like 1234567890 and its used in whats app so how to find its used in whatsapp in my application contact list?

Comment: What have tried?  Are there problems with the code you are trying to get to work?

Comment: still now not tring any code only search for that if you have any solution explain me how to do that?

Comment: use this link  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35453979/4395114 for whole description and with flow of data store table of android contacts

Answer (score 24):

With the `READ_CONTACTS` permission in your manifest, you can get synced contacts given the account type. For WhatsApp it's `"com.whatsapp"`. So:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
        RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] { RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY },
        RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ?",
        new String[] { "com.whatsapp" },
        null);

ArrayList<String> myWhatsappContacts = new ArrayList<String>();
int contactNameColumn = c.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY);
while (c.moveToNext())
{
    // You can also read RawContacts.CONTACT_ID to read the
    // ContactsContract.Contacts table or any of the other related ones.
    myWhatsappContacts.add(c.getString(contactNameColumn));
}
```

Comment: @matiash it's returning Contact name, what about the numbers?

Comment: @CodeGuru You can query the Data table with the contact id returned by this query. All the information for the contact should be there.

Comment: @VijayRajput how can i get whatsapp contact number? I am only getting name.

Answer (score 0):

myWhatsappContacts ArrayList will contain all the phone numbers that are present in your whatsapp Application.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI 
                  ,new String[] {ContactsContract.Data._ID
                               ,ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME
                               ,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER 
                               ,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE}
                  ,ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                  + "' AND " + ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ?"
                  ,new String[] { "com.whatsapp" }
                  , null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {

        myWhatsappContacts.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))); 

    }
```

Comment: thanks man. that helped a'lot. (Is it also possible to send a number to whatsApp and get response if that number is on whatsapp? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61269646/get-check-whatsapp-numbers-from-android-programmatically )

Answer (score 0):

System.out.print("Name : "+cursor.getString(contactNameColumn) +"\n "+" Phone Number" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));