# Android Content resolver Returns all accounts activated in mobile No

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contacts, contactscontract

While trying to retrieve a contact list from android using the below code it returns multiple accounts like google/gmail, whatsapp, and soma (how many accounts are activated depends on the number content resolver returns for that much copy of contact !).
Please help me to remove it.

```
 cursor1=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI ,null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME +" ASC");              
 startManagingCursor(cursor1);
String[] from = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,}; 
  int[] to = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}; 
listadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor1, from, to);        
 setListAdapter(listadapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpy try the below code which has more validations and also check for if it has phone number or not. But your andorid device's contacts should be well arranged.

```
   private void displayContacts() {
     
      ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                  String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                  String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                  if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                     Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                               null,
                               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                               new String[]{id}, null);
                     while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                         String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                         Toast.makeText(NativeContentProvider.this, "Name: " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                    pCur.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You may also get some filteration of account here like filtering out of what's app account by using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24276984) which fetches what's app contacts from phone contacts.

Comment: it'll show duplicate because they are duplicate in your phone contacts provider, But if they are merge(join) account with same name, then there'll not be duplicate values with same name, all accounts will be considered as same.

Comment: already merged it  !!! but still no way  buddy ,and my contact list in mobile phone seems fine and without duplicating and apps like imo shows only one contact , I just want  solution like that :(

Comment: then get the single number with the same id of your contact which is unique even for your every type of account .

Comment: my pleasure, was that helpful to use?

Comment: ya of course i have added some codes with it any way thumbs up ;)

Comment: cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI ,null, RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "!= ?" ,  new String[] { "com.whatsapp" }, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME +" ASC");