# how to separate the whats app contacts from mobile contacts in android device

Tags: java, android, json, android-activity, package

```
  ArrayList<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>();

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            String contactName = c
                    .getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phNumber = c
                    .getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            contacts.add(contactName + ":" + phNumber);

        }
        c.close();
        return contacts;
```

i use this code for getting mobile contacts and how to separate the whats app contacts from all mobile contacts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24276573/how-to-get-contacts-which-are-used-in-whatsapp-or-other-application-in-android

Answer (score 0):

use this code to get all whatsapp contact and save it it array list

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
        RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ?",
        new String[] { "com.whatsapp" }, null);

ArrayList<String> WContacts = new ArrayList<String>();

int indexNumber = cursor
        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

    WContacts.add(cursor.getString(indexNumber));
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply .... . Am getting the all contacts ,am not able to identify the whats app contacts in device.

Comment: and also the above code gives only the contact names not contact number

Comment: do not forget permission    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />