# Open Whatsapp contacts list from android app

Tags: android, whatsapp

I am new to android and trying to do following task:-
I want to open Whatsapp contact list and get selected contact data. I am able to achieve half of the work. Whatsapp contact list opens , but once i press on any contact my app crashes. Here is my code:

To open Whatsapp contact list:

```
btnChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            try{
                Toast.makeText(AddScheduleActivity.this, "going out activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                Toast.makeText(AddScheduleActivity.this, "getting In activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(AddScheduleActivity.this, "Whatsapp not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //no activity found to handle this intent means whatsapp is not installed
            }
        }
    });
```

To get selection:-

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    Toast.makeText(AddScheduleActivity.this, "Ok In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                if(intent.hasExtra("contact")){

                    Toast.makeText(AddScheduleActivity.this, "Ok working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Uri uri = intent.getData();
                    //Query the content uri
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    // column index of the phone number
                    int  phoneIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                    // column index of the contact name
                    int  nameIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                    contactNumber = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
                    name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);

                }
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

If i don't select any contact and press back , their is no crash in that case

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the application crashes, include the logcat in your question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24276573/how-to-get-contacts-which-are-used-in-whatsapp-or-other-application-in-android Already, a similar question is asked.Just check whether this works for you.

Comment: @baymaxx Thanks but i already seen it, its not helpful

Comment: @Priyanka Whats the reason that your app is getting crashed? Use the debugger in android studio..Atleast finding that error can help us find the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue myself. Here is edited code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                if(intent.hasExtra("contact")){
                    String number = intent.getStringExtra("contact");

                    Toast.makeText(AddScheduleActivity.this, number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`intent.getdata()` will always return null.

Use `intent.getExtras().getString("contact");` to get the contact number.

Comment: @AshwaniGarg Thanks for your answer but this solution is not helpful to me as i am not even able to see "Ok In" toast.

Comment: just like "contact" can we use it for getting name e.g intent.getExtras().getString("name");